# Display elements in a inline-block depend on section width

Tags: html, css, sass

I have tried for some time to do something like on the image.

Elements (.element) goes down but they are not centered but stick left.

My code now is:

Html:

```
<div id="_technology_page" class="region">
    <div class="actions_container">
        <div class="actions">
            {{#each actions}}
            <div class="action">
                <a href="{{link}}">
                    <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
                    <p class="action_text">
                        {{text}}
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css: (scss):

```
#_technology_page {
    .actions_container {
        max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        .actions {
            position: relative;
            .action {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                position: relative;
                margin: 10px 40px;
                text-align: center;
                float: left;
                height: 300px;
                width: 250px;
                display: flex;
                img {
                    margin: auto;
                    width: 120px
                }
                .action_text {
                    width: 100%;
                    color: black;
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many things, search examples, bot nothing works as I want it to works.

Also, I have tried to do it on Bootstrap grid system, but those elements are still stuck to the left side of the container.

Please provide some examples how to do it, I have no idea how to do it anymore.

[image: howto]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `flexbox` here is a way simpler code from yours

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.region {
  border: solid;
  padding: 50px 0
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: red solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.action {
  flex: 0 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border: orange solid;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="_technology_page" class="region">
  <div class="actions_container">
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="action">
        <a href="{{link}}">
          <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
          <p class="action_text">
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <a href="{{link}}">
          <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
          <p class="action_text">
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <a href="{{link}}">
          <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
          <p class="action_text">
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <a href="{{link}}">
          <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
          <p class="action_text">
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <a href="{{link}}">
          <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
          <p class="action_text">
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <a href="{{link}}">
          <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
          <p class="action_text">
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <a href="{{link}}">
          <img src="/img/technology/grafiki/{{icon}}.png" alt="">
          <p class="action_text">
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! That is what I need. Thanks so much.